# Как происходит шифрование через сервер когда общаются 2 клиента?

Tags: безопасность, клиент-сервер, криптография, rsa

Существует клиент-серверный чат с шифрованием. Вопросы следующие:

1. При соединении клиента1 с клиентом2, где генерируются открытые и закрытые ключи?
2. Когда ключи сгенерированы, клиенты обмениваются публичными ключами для шифрования писем?
3. Как защитить подключение от перехвата человеком посередине или по-другому, как сделать верификацию пользователя с которым ты будешь общаться?
4. или дайте наконец ссылку где я смогу подробно про это все прочитать:)

Comment: (1) А вы уже зафиксировали, что будет асимметричное шифрование? (2) Если на предыдущий вопрос "да", то да, это самый простой, но не единственный вариант. (3) С помощью третьей стороны (CA) или стороннего канала связи. (4) Про что именно?

Comment: @D-side (1) а каким образом это нужно фиксировать?(3) то есть, к примеру, https это делается именно так: "С помощью третьей стороны (CA) или стороннего канала связи"? ссылку на подробную схему взаимодействия, начиная от подключения, клиента-сервера-клиента с шифрованием.

Comment: (1) Скажем, почему не симметричное, где ключ у обеих сторон один? (3) Да, HTTPS **обычно** опирается на CA. На схеме изображать толком нечего: сервер отправляет свои сертификаты, клиент устанавливает их подлинность по подписям известным ему заранее CA (ЦС).

Comment: @D-side (1) один ключ это же не безопасно и ТЗ такое:) хотелось бы почитать где-нибудь подробное описание, т.к. нужно будет реализовать данный алгоритм. под подробным описанием я имею в виду все: начиная от подключения клиентов к серверу и заканчивая последним переданным байтом для установления защищенного соединения и защищенной передачи данных; все цифровые подписи, ключи, обмен последними, верификация и еще, то чего я не назвал, что нужно для процесса подключения.

Comment: (1) Это заблуждение, а вот ТЗ уже аргумент. Тот же HTTPS использует для самого соединения симметричное шифрование. А RSA/DH/и т.д. используются лишь чтобы договориться об общем ключе.

Comment: @D-side вот поэтому я прошу помощи:)